# Why doesn't (into {} x) accept a sequence of sequences for x

Tags: clojure

```
=> (into {} (for [x [["1" "2"] ["3" "4"]]] (map #(Long/parseLong %) x)))
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.ATransientMap.conj (ATransientMap.java:44)

=> (into {} (for [x [["1" "2"] ["3" "4"]]] (seq (map #(Long/parseLong %) x))))
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.ATransientMap.conj (ATransientMap.java:44)

=> (into {} (for [x [["1" "2"] ["3" "4"]]] (vec (map #(Long/parseLong %) x))))
{1 2, 3 4}
```

I've got two related questions:

1. How come `(into {})` insists on vector as the container of a (key,value) pair?
2. Why is it trying to use the `Long`, which is the constituent of the pair, as the pair itself? Shouldn't it at least complain about seeing a non-vector, regardless of what it contains?

---

BTW testing with Clojure 1.5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the second question: you're passing a sequence of sequences to `into`. `into` works by repeated `conj`ing (or `conj!`ing, if possible; the result is equivalent). Here at each step you'll be taking one item from your sequence of sequences and `conj`ing it on to the map. Each such item is a sequence of two `Long`s. When you `conj` a sequence on to a map, `conj` assumes that it is a sequence of map entries and casts each element to `Map$Entry`. 
So, here it'll be attempting to cast your `Long`s to `Map$Entry`.

Comment: This actually answers the first question as well.

Answer (score 4):

`into` is implemented on top of `conj`.

```
(into {} ...) ;; equivalent to (below)
(-> {}
    (conj (map #(Long/parseLong %) ["1" "2"])  ;; produces the same exception
    (conj (map #(Long/parseLong %) ["3" "4"]))
```

`conj` expects either a map, a map entry or a two-element vector. Consider this excerpt from http://clojure.org/data_structures#toc17:

> conj expects another (possibly single entry) map as the item, and returns a new map which is the old map plus the entries from the new, which may overwrite entries of the old. conj also accepts a MapEntry or a vector of two items (key and value).